# unknown error in realm studio for windows

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

After downloading `Realm browser`, i tried to connect it with our linux server where `Realm Object Server` is installed (professional edition).
Initially it was showing Timeout error constantly after that i tried to run `Realm Studio` as administrator and it started working.

I was trying run [EventBlank example](https://github.com/realm-demos/EventBlank/tree/master/server) provided by realm

i was able to create database and users too over realm and can see it on realm studio but after a while when i tried to reopen realm studio and connect with the same realm object server url it is throwing `unknown error`

[image: Realm Studio Error]

here is the server log while unknown error occured

[image]

Timeout error

[image]

Following things i have tried

1) re install realm studio
2) while installing run it as admin 
3) turning off the firewall on windows

but it still throwing unknown error and timeout error

I am running realm object server using

```
ros start --address <ipaddress> --port <port>
```

server start log

[image]

After inspecting , this is what i got ( i have updated realm studio to 1.4 )

[image]

Comment: You can check the actual error by opening the Developer Tools in Realm Studio, because it is an Electron app so it can do that. Press Ctrl + Alt + I

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + I worked for me , have updated the progress in question

Comment: not sure why this error is occurring but it is eating up my days and my trial is getting expired !!!

Comment: I would love to see the stacktrace from that error - to get a quick fix please shoot me an email on kraen.hansen@realm.io and we can connect on Skype / Hangouts, and update this thread when we solve the issue.

Another thing: I see that you are supplying address and port when your starting ROS, that might not be required with your setup, if you don't provide them ROS will listen on all network interfaces (including that with IP 192.168.100.251) and use the default port (9080).